# Selectize Js trigger onload automatically

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

Is there a way to trigger select on load. I am using selectize plugin. This plugin not getting triggered on load. Once select manually, it works.

https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js

Here i need to compare option ID with IP detect country value. For example, if both AU, trigger that option.

**HTML**

```
<select name="select" id="select" >
<option id="EN" value="global.html">Global</option>
<option id="AU" value="australia.html">Australia</option>
<option id="ID" value="Indonesia.html">Indonesia</option>
</select>
```

**In browser it render as below format:**

```
<select name="select" id="select" class="custom-select elem-width selectized" placeholder="Select Country" data-validation="required" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
    <option value="others.html" selected="selected"></option>
</select>

<div class="selectize-control custom-select elem-width single">
    <div class="selectize-input items full has-options has-items">
        <div data-value="others.html" class="item">Others</div>
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="" style="width: 106px; opacity: 0; display: inline-block;">
    </div>
    <div class="selectize-dropdown custom-select elem-width single" style="display: none; visibility: visible; width: 235px; top: 40px; left: 0px;">
        <div class="selectize-dropdown-content">
            <div data-value="others.html" data-selectable="" class="option selected">Others</div>
            <div data-value="US.html" data-selectable="" class="option">United States (US)</div>
            <div data-value="kr.html" data-selectable="" class="option">Korea</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function getCode () {
var now = new Date().getTime();
var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
var uniqueNumber = now + 'a' + randomNumber;
$.getScript("getCountryCode.js?" + uniqueNumber, function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    if (country){
       var code = country;
       console.log("countryCode:" + countryCode);
       $('.selectize-dropdown-content div').trigger('change');
     }
});
}
```

Comment: Why are you including `$` twice??  `$($('.selectize-dropdown-content div'))`?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more code - the code you've provided isn't enough to narrow down the solution

Comment: @GuruprasadRao - Not both.. tried either one.. but both not working

Comment: @Venkiweb Just remove one `$` and keep it like this `$('.selectize-dropdown-content div').trigger('change');`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Sorry..by mistake added another in query.. But in code, it was single.. Please check my updated HTML & JS

Comment: Does the `console.log` fire?

Comment: yes... it detects and output correct location as AU.  Only trigger function not working

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your `json` data which is returned to `ajax` call will be in below format:

```
data={"country":"australia.html","countryCode":"AU"}
```

Now you will check whether `data` is valid with country name present using `if(data.country)`. Then you can use the below code to change the value!! No need to `trigger` change! All you need is to set the value using `setValue` option of `selectize` as below:

```
var data={"country":"australia.html","countryCode":"AU"}
if (data.country){
       var code = data.countryCode;
       console.log("countryCode:" + code);
        var $select = $("#select").selectize();
        var selectize = $select[0].selectize;
        selectize.setValue(data.country); 
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/p3aqvdtj/)**

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But, i need to call all scripts within this function. Also selectize() cant initialise here. Only triggering inner div is causing the issue here.. Remaining things are loading fine.

Comment: What is in your `data` returned from `$.getScript`? and how you are getting values of `country` and `countryCode`? Are you getting them from the script?

Comment: yes.. getting them from script. Trigger action not getting inside the div container

Comment: See according to their documentation you should target `trigger` on actual element instead of on the structure created by `plugin`. You are triggering `change` Ok but are you telling what to change to the plugin? I think you should use `setValue` to change the `select` option once obtained from script!

Comment: Updated my above question with HTML render format for select list. Selectize plugin renders <select> elements to rendered version (updated on top). Have to Trigger that div element to change. Thanks